# plotting a scalogram how to select levels in contourf

Tags: python, plot, data-visualization, wavelet, wavelet-transform

I'm trying to plot the output of a continuous wavelet transform of a signal that I have. The signal is just a cosine wave whose frequency decrease with time. I'm just using it to test the plotting function.

I have a function that plots the scalogram of the CWT but I'm struggling on how to pick the correct levels range to use for my contour lines.

**What i would like to know:**

1. Is increasing the amount of levels basically just making the difference between color regions smaller? With more levels the difference between adjacent levels is smaller?
2. If you look at the below plots you notice how there appears to be more distinct regions in the first plot (with more levels) So I would think this is a good thing. In the bottom plot the use of less levels we see that whole large dark red section as one color instead of a few different shades.

I appreciate any feedback/comments/answers or if you see any mistakes. Thank you so much!

the function I'm using to create the plots:

```py
def plot_wavelet(ax, time2, signal, scales, waveletname = 'cmor', 
      cmap =plt.cm.seismic, title = '', ylabel = '', xlabel = ''):

    dt=time2
    coefficients, frequencies = pywt.cwt(signal, scales, waveletname, dt)
    print ("coeff shape is:",coefficients.shape)
    print ("frequency shape is:", frequencies.shape)
    power = (abs(coefficients)) ** 2
    period = frequencies

    # different level lists to test 
    levels = [0.015625, 0.03125, 0.0625, 0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16] #option 1
    #levels = [0.015625, 0.03125, 0.0625, 0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 1] #option 2

    contourlevels = np.log2(levels) #convert to log2 for plotting
    time=range(2048) # Sampling frequency is 2048, so this is a 1 second sample

    im = ax.contourf(time, np.log2(period), np.log2(power), contourlevels, extend='both',cmap=cmap)

    ax.set_title(title, fontsize=20)
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel, fontsize=18)
    ax.set_xlabel(xlabel, fontsize=18)

    yticks = 2**np.arange(np.ceil(np.log2(period.min())), np.ceil(np.log2(period.max())))

    ax.set_yticks(np.log2(yticks)) #original
    ax.set_yticklabels(yticks) #original
    ax.invert_yaxis()

    ylim = ax.get_ylim()
    cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.95, 0.5, 0.03, 0.25])
    fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_ax, orientation="vertical")

    return yticks, ylim
```

**The only difference between the two plots below are the levels used, everything else is the same:**

This is the plot with levels = [0.015625, 0.03125, 0.0625, 0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16]

[image]

This is the plot with levels = [0.015625, 0.03125, 0.0625, 0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 1]

[image]